# A question about convergence of functions involving Q-Pochhammer symbols

Tags: complex-analysis, infinite-product, absolute-convergence

Consider the function $H:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$:

$$H(s)=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{2^{ns}}\right)$$

$H(s)$ is convergent on $\Re(s)>0$. Is it absolutely convergent on $\Re(s)>1$

Comment: How do you define absolute convergence for infinite products? That no matter how you permute factors you will get the same result? Or that the product of every subsequence converges?

Comment: The absolute convergence of $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+z_n)$ means that $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+|z_n|)<\infty $ and $\prod_{n=N}^\infty (1-|z_n|)>0 $ for $N$ large enough.

Comment: @Ryszard Szwarc Thanks. I think then it is. At least as far as I can quickly check with Mathematica, on the domain I am interested in, Re(s)>1. Many thanks. I will see if I can sketch a proof of it. and post it as an answer, or maybe someone else will.

Comment: @Ryszard Szwarc In fact, it seems it is absolutely convergent all the way down to 0. I will have to double check this when I have more time. Many thanks.

Comment: A necessary and sufficient condition for the convergence $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+|z_n|)$ as well as for  $\prod_{n=N}^\infty (1-|z_n|) >0$ for large $N$  is $\sum |z_n|<\infty.$

Comment: @Ryszard Szwarc Thank you once again. Would you have a text or a reference where I could look this and other things up as well?

Comment: Try [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/~jmckerna/Teaching/14-15/Autumn/220A/l_23.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjJwMfMq_X7AhVk-IsKHeHBA1s4FBAWegQIDRAB&usg=AOvVaw261SMkTP7cNVIMpy_WJHl6)

Comment: @Ryszard Szwarc Many thanks!!